# How to set rows and columns in a table with colspan and rowspan?

Tags: html, html-table

```html
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr height="100">
        <td>DAB1</td>
        <td>DAB2</td>
        <td>DAB3</td>
        <td>DAB4</td>
        <td>DAB5</td>
    </tr>

    <tr height="50">
        <td colspan="2">DAB6</td>
        <td colspan="3">DAB7</td>
    </tr>

    <tr height="50">
        <td colspan="3">DAB8</td>
        <td colspan="2">DAB9</td>
    </tr>

    <tr height="50">
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">DAB10</td>
        <td colspan ="3">DAB11</td>
    </tr>

    <tr height="50">
        <td colspan="3">DAB12</td>
    </tr>

    <tr height="50" >
        <td>DAB13</td>
        <td>DAB14</td>
        <td>DAB15</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm having trouble with merging boxes in table. I have homework and I can't seem to reproduce the image properly. I dont understand how I am supposed to make `DAB 13-14-15` (shown below) **33%** of the table and if that's even possible.

Is the first row supposed to be merging two rows? Because when I try to use `rowspan="2"` on `DAB 1-2-3-4-5` cells, they show up on the right, so I had to it with `height`.

**I need to get this:**
[image]

**This is what comes out:**
[image]

**This is my code so far, I just don't understand how rows work:**

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr height="100">
        <td>DAB1</td>
        <td>DAB2</td>
        <td>DAB3</td>
        <td>DAB4</td>
        <td>DAB5</td>
    </tr>

    <tr height="50">
        <td colspan="2">DAB6</td>
        <td colspan="3">DAB7</td>
    </tr>

    <tr height="50">
        <td colspan="3">DAB8</td>
        <td colspan="2">DAB9</td>
    </tr>

    <tr height="50">
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">DAB10</td>
        <td colspan ="3">DAB11</td>
    </tr>

    <tr height="50">
        <td colspan="3">DAB12</td>
    </tr>

    <tr height="50" >
        <td>DAB13</td>
        <td>DAB14</td>
        <td>DAB15</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Here is a hint: you need to make a 15x16 table.

Comment: So I should make 15x16 first and then merge?

Comment: Just think of your overall table as 15x16 and figure how many rows and cols each td needs to span in order to reach the desired shape.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `height` attribute is depreciated and not a good practice anyways.
Think of how many rows and columns you need first, then you go with `colspan` and `rowspan` attributes.

**Run the code snippet so see an example.**

```css
td {
border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1.1</td>
    <td>1.2</td>
    <td rowspan="2">1.3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">2.1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, 
`rowspan="2"` uses space that would normally take 2 `<td>` tags vertically, 
 
(which means one `<td>` tag in each `<tr>` tags)

`colspan="2"` uses space that would normally take 2 `<td>` tags horizontally.
 
(which means two `<td>` tags in the same `<tr>` tag)